# VS 2015 RC freezes when trying to edit files in solution

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2015

Have an instance of VS 2015 RC.  Using Git and TFS.
Yesterday I attempted a sync unaware I was offline at the moment.  Was able to restore network connection and sync alright.  After that, every time I attempt to edit (text editor) a file (C#) VS freezes on typing the first character.

I can add files to the solution, but that is about it.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: This has been resolved.  The issue was network related.
There were network outages reported at the time the issue started to present itself.

Under Tools-Options-Projects and Solutions
The locations all pointed to shared network locations.  Changed to local drive.

Comment: UPDATE After almost a full day without the issue VS froze again. Disabled JustCode and it seems to be working well again.

Answer (score 0):

Check your network connection!

This has been resolved.  The issue was network related. There were network outages reported at the time the issue started to present itself.

The network connection was switched between wired and wifi networks and then back to wired.  Today, the wired network seems stable.

Under Tools-Options-Projects and Solutions
The locations all pointed to shared network locations.  Changed to local drive.

**UPDATE**
After almost a full day without the issue VS froze again.
Disabled JustCode and it seems to be working well again.